# Is 8bit Content-Transfer-Encoding Considered RFC 5322 Compliant?

Tags: email

What I'm trying to ascertain is whether or not emails containing 8-bit characters (in the range `%x80-%xFF`) - which could appear in messages or sections with a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header of `8bit` or `binary` - can ever be considered RFC 5322-compliant.

I am looking for something like an industry consensus on this question, if anyone is aware of such a thing; the relevant spec documents appear to be somewhat contradictory.

Google's new [email sending guidelines](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126?hl=en#zippy=%2Crequirements-for-all-senders) state that messages must be compliant with RFC 5322, as do [Yahoo's](https://senders.yahooinc.com/best-practices/), so compliance is an issue to be treated seriously here.

**Exhibit 1:**

RFC 5322 [states](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-2.1):

> Note: This document specifies that messages are made up of characters in the US-ASCII range of 1 through 127.  There are other documents, specifically the MIME document series ([RFC2045], [RFC2046], [RFC2047], [RFC2049], [RFC4288], [RFC4289]), that extend this specification to allow for values outside of that range.  Discussion of those mechanisms is not within the scope of this specification.

I feel that leaves the matter of whether the MIME series documents describe *compliant* extensions to RFC 5322, or *non-compliant* extensions / elaborations, exactly as ambiguous as it was before the above paragraph was written. In other words, per [RFC 2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045), an email containing 8-bit characters may be considered a valid email, **but is it a valid RFC 5322 email?**

**Exhibit 2:**

The ABNF for [overall message syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.5) in RFC 5322 reads:

```
message         =   (fields / obs-fields)
                       [CRLF body]

body            =   (*(*998text CRLF) *998text) / obs-body

text            =   %d1-9 /            ; Characters excluding CR
                   %d11 /             ;  and LF
                   %d12 /
                   %d14-127
```

This would appear to conclusively forbid the use of characters outside the 7-bit range anywhere in the message body. If I was writing a draconian parser based solely on ABNF given in RFC 5322, octets above `%d127` would fail validation.

**Exhibit 3:**

Conversely, RFC 2045, which was written 12 years earlier and to which RFC 5322 makes explicit reference, [provides](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045#section-6.2) for two values of `Content-Transfer-Encoding` that allow 8-bit characters in message bodies.

**Exhibit 4:**

In a test message, Google chose to encode a message body containing all ASCII characters plus 'ö' using a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` of `quoted-printable`, despite the fact that the message could have been sent with `8bit` as simple UTF-8.

**Exhibit 5:**

[Word on th'Internet](https://noxxi.de/research/breaking-dkim-on-purpose-and-by-chance.html) is that use of `8bit` could sometimes break DKIM validation prior to widespread adoption of the 8BITMIME SMTP extension, as a forwarding server would be forced to transcode the message body upon negotiating with a receiving MTA which did not support 8-bit characters at the protocol level. As Google & Yahoo's current mail initiative is largely centred around trust and authentication, they may see even a tiny risk of such problems as unacceptable.

**Exhibit 6:**

RFC 6376 (DKIM) also [states](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-5.3) that messages should be converted to 7-bit form before signing with DKIM anyway, to avoid these kinds of errors.

**Summary:**

The question has two related forms, both centred on the meaning of compliance to RFC 5322:

1. Will Google and Yahoo begin rejecting valid RFC 2045 email using `Content-Transfer-Encoding` of `8bit`, on the grounds that it is *not* valid RFC 5322 email?
2. Should a draconian RFC 5322 parser (validator) reject messages with bodies containing 8-bit characters, even if they use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`?

Comment: Their public MXes offering 8BITMIME is nothing less than a promise to also accept RFC 2045, on top of RFC 5322.

Comment: @anx I do wish I shared your confidence; at the moment they (Google at least) are in the process of phasing in changes on a small percentage of transactions, so we may not know the real answer here until the summer when they plan to apply the new rules to 100% of incoming email. In any case it doesn't really answer my question RE the strictest interpretation of compliance, which is really what I need to know.